# why would I hide text in css / what is that for?

Tags: html, css

There are multiple ways to hide text in css.
For example,
1)

```
text-indent: 9999px
```

2)

```
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

but what would people usually do that for?

And I understand what text-indent:10px does , but what does "text-indent 100%" (i.e. percentage) do?

Answer (score 0):

Well  when ever you have an element that has the `text-indent | margin-left/right | left/right` properties set to `100%` or some big number, this usually makes the element's position either hide if its `parent` container has either `overflow: hidden` or if the properties' `value` place the element outside of the `window` or `viewport`.

Any element of the `DOM` that can use the `CSS` properties to be placed somewhere in the `page` i.e. uses  `text-indent | margin-left/right | left/right` amongst others,  the `%` (percentage) uses  relative positioning depending on its parent's `dimensions`.

**e.g**

If you have:

```
#parent{
 width: 500px;
}

#child{
  width: 100%;
}

<div id="parent">
   <div id="child"> </div>
</div>
```

Then the `child` will have `width: 100%` **relative** to its `parent` so it would have a width of `500px` as this is the 100% of the parent's width.

**The reasons?**

1. styling
2. For animation purposes.
3. Maybe for security:

**Why security?**

One way to prevent a bot from creating an account on your website is to create for example an `input` with `left/right: -100%/100%` or some **big** number and this will make the **user** not **see** the input, **but the bot will**, so when recieving the input data in the server side, **if** the *"hidden"* input is filled, you will know that something is wrong.